# Set the database current timestamp while inserting using JOOQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I am using the following code segment to do the insertion using JOOQ's `UpdatableRecord`.

```
public void acknowledgeDisclaimer(AcknowledgeDisclaimerReq acknowledgeDisclaimerReq) {
        DisclaimerRecord disclaimerRecord = dslContext.newRecord(Disclaimer.DISCLAIMER);
        disclaimerRecord.setDisclaimerForId(acknowledgeDisclaimerReq.getDealListingId());
        disclaimerRecord.setDisclaimerForType("DEAL");
        disclaimerRecord.setAcceptedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        disclaimerRecord.setAcceptedByOwnerId(acknowledgeDisclaimerReq.getLoggedInOwnerId());
        int count = disclaimerRecord.store();
        log.info("Inserted entry for disclaimer for deal: {}, owner: {}, id {}, insertCount: {}", disclaimerRecord.getDisclaimerForId(), disclaimerRecord.getAcceptedByOwnerId(), disclaimerRecord.getId(), count);
}
```

When setting the `AcceptedAt` data, I want to use the database's current timestamp instead of passing the JVM timestamp. Is there any way to do that in JOOQ?

Comment: Set the default value for the column in the underlying SQL database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdatableRecord.store()` can only set `Field<T> => T` key/values, not `Field<T> => Field<T>`, so you cannot set an expression in your record. You can obviously run an explicit `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `MERGE` statement instead.

#### Using triggers

The best way to ensure such a timestamp is set to the database timestamp whenever you run some specific DML on the table is to use a database trigger (you could make the trigger watch for changes in the `ACCEPTED_BY_OWNER_ID` value)

If you can't do this on the server side (which is the most reliable, because it will behave correctly for all database clients, not just the JDBC/jOOQ based ones), you might have a few client side options in jOOQ:

#### Using jOOQ 3.17 client side computed columns

jOOQ 3.17 has added support for [stored (or virtual) client side computed columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-computed/), a special case of which are [audit columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-audit/) (which is almost what you're doing).

Using this, you can specify, for example:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <generator><![CDATA[
    ctx -> org.jooq.impl.DSL.currentTimestamp()
  ]]></generator>
  <includeExpression>(?i:ACCEPTED_AT)</includeExpression>
</forcedType>
```

The above acts like a trigger that sets the `ACCEPTED_AT` date to the current timestamp every time you write to the table. In your case, it'll be more like:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <generator><![CDATA[
    ctx -> org.jooq.impl.DSL
      .when(ACCEPTED_BY_OWNER_ID.isNotNull(), org.jooq.impl.DSL.currentTimestamp())
      .else_(ctx.table().ACCEPTED_AT)
  ]]></generator>
  <includeExpression>(?i:ACCEPTED_AT)</includeExpression>
</forcedType>
```

See a current limitation of the above here:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13809

See the relevant manual sections here:

- [Client side computed columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-computed/)
- [Audit columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-audit/)

Comment: Thanks, i will read about client side computed columns.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like `disclaimerRecord.setAcceptedAt(DSL.now());`

Comment: No it is not working